# I have installed C drive Windows 10, I want to install this C drive format and install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, drivers, system-installation, software-installation, windows

Help me,
I have installed C drive Windows 10, I want to install this C drive format and install Ubuntu.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS, new systems are UEFI, but how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS for both Windows & Ubuntu is then how it installs. And both systems need to be in same boot mode.  If UEFI: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Will Ubuntu be a dual boot alongside Windows 10 or a single boot?

Comment: Single boot only ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you only want Ubuntu and not Dual boot with Windows, the safest way to do this is:

Create a Unallocated Space via Windows OS, install Ubuntu on it in Dual OS mode.

After being done with installation, delete Windows boot entry from grub, then delete or format your Windows Volume with any suitable utility like Gparted etc, & you're done.

Why Install in Dual OS Mode and why not just deleting Windows Partiton right there from Ubuntu Installation?

Just to be there in a safer side. If anyhow, Ubuntu Installation fails you'll not have a Computer with no OS.

Comment: Too complicated IMHO. It is much easier to wipe the existing drive contents directly using Ubuntu installer.